# How to ACK celery tasks with parallel code in reactor?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, celery, reactor

I have a celery task that, when called, simply ignites the execution of some parallel code inside a twisted reactor. Here's some sample (not runnable) code to illustrate:

```
def run_task_in_reactor():
   # this takes a while to run
   do_something()
   do_something_more()


@celery.task
def run_task():
   print "Started reactor"
   reactor.callFromThread(run_task_in_reactor)
```

(For the sake of simplicity, please assume that the reactor is already running when the task is received by the worker; I used the signal `@worker_process_init.connect` to start my reactor in another thread as soon as the worker comes up)

When I call `run_task.delay()`, the task finishes pretty quickly (since it does not wait for `run_task_in_reactor()` to finish, only schedules its execution in the reactor). And, when `run_task_in_reactor()` finally runs, `do_something()` or `do_something_more()` can throw an exception, which will go unoticed.

Using `pika` to consume from my queue, I can use an ACK inside `do_something_more()` to make the worker notify the correct completion of the task, for instance. However, inside Celery, this does not seems to be possible (or, at least, I do't know how to accomplish the same effect)

Also, I cannot remove the reactor, since it is a requirement of some third-party code I'm using. Other ways to achieve the same result are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reactor.blockingCallFromThread` instead.

Comment: please explain where and how to use it, even including the codd of the question

Comment: @MauricioGracia It's really just `reactor.blockingCallFromThread` instead of `reactor.callFromThread` in the code of the question.